# go - Encoding gif image.Image

Tags: image, go

The image/jpeg and image/png packages have Decode and Encode functions that read and write jpeg and png images, but the image/gif package does not - only Decode and DecodeAll.

Any ideas then, on how to encode a gif image.Image into an io.Writer?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but would you clarify why PNG won't do?

Comment: Not really what you mean by that, or rather, how that would work. Definitely would if it's feasible.

Comment: I wondered whether you could simply encode your images as PNG. Unless you need animation (only GIF supports this) or ultra-tiny 1-pixel images (which are best hand-crafted), PNG is technically superior in all other respects. As you remarked, Go supports PNG encoding. Would this do what you need in your app?

Comment: I'm afraid not, want animation. For now I'm just blocking gif files - leaving that feature for later. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Go standard library doesn't include a GIF encoder.

I think your best bet will be to use [cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) to interface with a C library which encodes GIFs.  [giflib](http://giflib.sourceforge.net/gif_lib.html) looks reasonably straight forward.

Alternatively you could port the [relevant parts of giflib](http://sourceforge.net/p/giflib/code/ci/master/tree/lib/) to go and submit them to the standard library.

There is a historical reason why GIF encoding isn't widespread - it was covered by patents on the LZW compression used.  However those patents have now expired so there is no reason not to have a compressor in the standard library other than the fact that GIFs aren't as popular as they used to be!

Comment: This is outdated. `image/gif` includes a GIF encoder for a while now.